# Hibernate SessionFactory is not saving changes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The code below silently fails to update the database. There is no error message to report here. It seems as if the line "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(sn);" (towards the bottom of the snippet) is being ignored. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public String getSerialNumber(String id) {
    log.debug("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Looking for Serial number counter named: " + id);
    SerialNumber sn = (SerialNumber) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(SerialNumber.class, id);
    if (sn == null) {
        //TODO Throw an error (maybe). The code below creates a new Serial number counter
        log.debug("NO Serial Number for: " + id + " was found.");

        sn = new SerialNumber();
        sn.setSerialNumberId(id);
        sn.setName("Unspecified");
        sn.setValue(1);
        log.debug("-----------------------------------------" + sn.toString());
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(sn);
        log.debug("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Right after SAVE call. This is id --> " + id);
        return "1";
    }

    sn.setValue(sn.getValue()+1);
    log.debug("--update---------------------------------" + sn.toString());
    log.debug("--update---------------------------------" + sn.getValue());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(sn);

    log.debug("--update---------------------------------" + sn.getValue());
    log.debug("--update------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Right after SAVE call. This is id --> " + id);
    return sn.getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: Wrap the code around a try catch an see if an exception is being thrown anywhere.

Comment: How would I do a commit? (I know it's not a good question but I am on first leg of learning curve and spend most of my day wanting to throw the computer off the roof! I love Java but some days I want to kill it!!)

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_plain_JDBC.  Alternatively, it may commit if you close your session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a new object. copy the fields from the old object and do a saveorupdate(new object)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your changes are not being committed to the database.  You need to commit a transaction or close the session.

Here's a simple transaction commit

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

 // your changes

 tx.commit();  // or you can rollback on exceptions
```